# Android - how to solve long server response waiting time?

Tags: android, android-service

Do you have any ideas on how to solve in an android long time of waiting on server response?

1. I am making a request to the API saving profile.
2. This request is fast
3. But the server is processing it rather long 10sec to 3min (like scanning cheap flight on some tickets sites)
4. After the response, I need to redirect the user to a confirmation screen or home screen of the app.

I solved this by setting the longer timeout to 45 sec and then always redirecting to confirmation + alert that it takes longer. 
On the home screen, I am displaying "Processing..." label until the server finishes

But this solution has some problems like:
what about user going out by home button if it takes longer, or switching applications, and if just display goes to sleep while untouched more than 30sec? Then activity/fragment is recreated and response seems to not arrive.

I consider adding push notification when processing is done this could help a little. Is there any way to solve such an issue? Maybe some background Service? But isn't Android Services deprecated? I think only Foreground Services are valid to use, or maybe new WorkManagers (but this doesn't seem to fit this scenario). And how from then wakeup screen and move it to the next page.

Code sample:

```
// Fragment 
viewModel.saveData(data)

// View Model 

fun saveData(data: Data) : LiveData<Resource<DataResponse>> {

        _dataEvent.postValue(Event(Resource.loading(null)))

        val apiSource = dataRepo.saveData(data)

        _dataEvent.addSource(apiSource) { resource ->
            _dataEvent.removeSource(apiSource)

            val resource = resource ?: Resource.error(null, null)
            _dataEvent.postValue(Event(resource))
        }

        return apiSource
    }

// Observing Data Event 

viewModel.dataEvent.observe(this,
                Observer { event ->

                    if(event?.peekContent()?.status == Resource.Status.LOADING) {
                        showProgressAlert(context)
                        event.getContentIfNotHandled() // consume loading event
                    }

                    val resource = event?.getContentIfNotHandled()
                    if(resource != null) {
                        hideProgressAlert()

                        if (resource.status == Resource.Status.SUCCESS) {
                            showSuccessAlert(context)
                           navigateToConfirmPage()
    } else if (resource.status == Resource.Status.ERROR) {

    if (throwable is SocketTimeoutException) {
        showTimeoutAlert(context)
        navigateToConfirmPage()
    } else { 
        showErrorAlert(context)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please post appropriate code here

Answer (score 0):

If this request is taking a long time then you should perform it in a background thread, Since android oreo background services became very restricted if you want to implement it you can use `JobIntentService` or `JobScheduler` or make it a `ForegroundService` but in this case you will have to show a notification to the user while the service is running, You can read more about it here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Another approach is to use `RXjava` which handles threading and perform background services very smoothly

Comment: what about WorkManager as it is replacement of JobScheduler? and how I can communicate from such ex. ForegroundService back to Fragment to show dialog with success/error and navigate to next step? I also do not want to block user on this step for 3min. just let it know it will be informed later about data being saved

Comment: You talk about RXjava, I am using LiveData and View model, but it seems that when screen sleeps and then response doesn't arrive and when user wake up screen live data doesn't return new event anymore. Maybe RXjava is better in such scenarios. But I don't want to shift.

Comment: I didn't use WorkManager before but JobScheduler is simple and easy to use and for communicating from service to fragment you can use bound service or you can use broadcast receiver to send data from service to fragment, And you don't have to block the user while the background service is running unless you need the output of the service to proceed the app to the next step

Comment: RXjava and LiveData are both built on Observables but i dont know if RXjava will be better in your scenario or not

Comment: What I know WorkManager replaces JobScheduler, AlertManager and other Firebase options. And this is for background task. But here I will rather go for Foreground Service as displaying notification is ok. But I have doubts how to solve this navigation. I don't want to block user for 3min, I want if response doesn't arrive in 30 sec just to navigate it to home. Maybe Foreground Service will be waiting infinitely for a reasponse with huge timeout like 5 min, and Fragment will have Timer to navigate foreword after 30sec. I

Comment: you can set your request timeout to 30sec and inside the foreground service if the request failed or timed out you can send broadcast to the fragment and when received navigate to home

Comment: I think I should give a try to this Foreground Service.